# Parse dictionary-like string value in PySpark from a csv file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I recently worked on a csv file using PySpark where a certain column contains values like a nested dictionary: `{'key1':'val1, 'key2':{'key3':'val3'}}`.

How should I specify a customized schema to parse it correctly? The desired outcome is to parse it as a string object: `"{'key1':'val1, 'key2':{'key3':'val3'}}"`.